# R Take the mean of duplicate rows within a dataset when some columns text within then

Tags: r

Hi I am trying to take the mean of duplicate sample rows within a data frame. I can produce the mean of all columns within the two rows, however some of my columns have text within then - this results in a lot of NA. How can I work around this?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. Can you post a minimal reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

If the rows are truly duplicated (as in, all of the values are the same), and assuming you have an ID variable that groups these duplicated rows, then you can simply take the first row for each ID.

Something like this may work:

```
library(dplyr)
new_data <- duplicated_data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Where `duplicated_data` is your original dataset, and `ID` is the ID variable that you use to determine whether a sample is duplicated or now.